# html content in gmail from firebase cloud functuion

Tags: html, gmail, google-cloud-functions

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```

I send email using firebase functioun and the mail is showing html code 
but i need to display html content not html code 
how to do this?
i resive mail as

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>table { font-family: arial, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}td, th { border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;}tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #dddddd;}</style></head><body><h2>HTML Table</h2><table> <tr> <th>Title</th> <th>Price</th> <th>Image</th> </tr> <tr>  <td>Aashirvaad Cumin Powder Pouch</td><td>6</td> <td><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2113/0893/products/Aashirvaad_Cumin_Powder_Pouch.png?v=1508267918"  height="102" width="102" alt="Girl in a jacket"></td></tr> <tr>  <td>Aashirvaad Chilli Powder Pouch</td><td>3</td> <td><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2113/0893/products/Aashirvaad_Chilli_Powder_Pouch.png?v=1508268124"  height="102" width="102" alt="Girl in a jacket"></td></tr> <tr>  <td>Aashirvaad Coriander Powder Pouch</td><td>1</td> <td><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2113/0893/products/Aashirvaad_Coriander_Powder_Pouch.png?v=1508268599"  height="102" width="102" alt="Girl in a jacket"></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

this and what i need is display as html

Comment: Show the code that how you are sending the email. Are you using `nodemailer` or something else. 
Show us code, inorder to get help

Comment: @nitishk72 i am using const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sending email to the user, you have two option sending

1. Sending Simple Text
2. Sending HTML Content

`Sending Simple Text` To send the simple text you need to send email data like this.

i.e :

```
var mailData = {
    from: 'sender@server.com',
    to: 'receiver@sender.com',
    subject: 'Message title',
    text: '<h1>This is not HTML Header</h1>',
};
```

`Sending HTML Content` In order to send HTML Content to the mail, you need to say about that.

i.e. :

```
var mailData = {
    from: 'sender@server.com',
    to: 'receiver@sender.com',
    subject: 'Message title',
    html: '<h1>This is HTML Header</h1>'
};
```

Comment: If this answer is correct then do accept it as correct